# Redis Cache hit / miss ratio, distribution and other metrics for springboot app

Tags: spring-boot, redis, prometheus, appdynamics, spring-micrometer

I have a springboot app instrumented with AppD, Micrometer and Prometheus.

Now I am using open source redis for in-memory distributed caching but i couldn't get the required statistics from it. please suggest.

1. A single redis cache is used to cache multiple methods with different ttl and other config.

The metrics i am interested in is as below.

1. cache hit / miss ratio for a particular cached method. Redis cli returns these values at an agregation level which also counts the reads from read replica's.
2. Cache distribution timinings.
3. Evacuations / expired keys and counts.

so far i couldn't figure out a way to do this. is there a way springboot / redis supports this or any other way in which this can be achieved.